# Grails 2.5.5 - How to improve the internationalization of error messages in service layer?

Tags: grails

I'm developing a web application where my business logic requires several types of error messages.

Due to this in my services layer I have several calls to the `messageSource`.

```
def messageSource
```

At the same time, my application must support several languages ​​so I need to define the `Locale` as specified by the user.

To do this, I'm getting the `Locale` as follows:

```
def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
Locale myLocale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
```

But I note that this code is repeated throughout my service layer. ie:

```
def myMethod(){
    ...
    messageSource.getMessage("message.code", [args] as Object[],"Default message",getLocale())
    ...
}

Locale getLocale(){
    def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
    return RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
}
```

Is there any elegant way to share this method among all my services and controllers? Or is there any other way to improve this behavior?

> Grails 2.5.5 - Groovy 2.4.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the methods in a Groovy trait, and then use the trait in your services.

**src/groovy/com/foo/bar/SessionLocale**

```
trait SessionLocale {
    def getMessage(String code, String defaultMessage, Object [] args) {
        messageSource.getMessage(code, args, defaultMessage,getLocale())
    }

    Locale getLocale(){
        def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
        return RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
    }
}
```

**grails-app/services/com/foo/bar/SomeService**

```
class SomeService implements SessionLocale {
    def myMethod(){
        ...
        getMessage("message.code", "Default message", [args] as Object[])
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If UserLocale is a trait so.. SomeService extends or implements UserLocale??

Comment: I though I tried implements and it didn't compile, but I think you're right and it should be implements. @injecteer LOL! Technically inheritance would work as well. But, if additional methods need to be reused then you'd end up with either a "god base class" or a confusing class hierarchy. A trait makes it possible to pull in just the needed behavior.

Comment: I just tried with implements and it works ;). Thanks!